# The one point compactification of a countable $KC$ space$X$ is $KC$ if and only if $X$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

The bellow Theorem is in " Spaces in which compact subsets are close and the lattice  of   $T_{1}$ topologies on sets" by " T.Alas , G.Wilson"

**The  one point compactification of a countable $KC$ space$X$ is $KC$ if and only if $X$ is compact.**

**proof:**

**sufficiency:** an open subspace of a sequential spaces is sequential.

**necessity:** supposr that $C$ is a compact subspace of the one point compatification $ Y = X \cup \{ ‎\infty‎ \}$of $X$. If $ \infty‎  \not\in C $ then $C$ is a compact subspace of $X$ , hence closed and so $ Y - C $ is open in $Y$.

if on the other  hand $‎\infty‎ \in C $, then if $C$ is notclosed in $Y$, $ C \cap X$ is not closed in$X$ and hence there is a sequence $\{ x_{n} \} $in $C \cap X $conerging to some $ p \not\in C $. Since $X$ is $KC$, the compact set$ S = \{p\} \cup \{ x_{n}  : n \in \omega \} $is closed in $X$ and so $ Y- S $ is a neighborhood of $\infty‎  $ and so $\infty‎  $ is not accumulation point of$\{ x_{n} \} $, implying that $C$ is not compact, a contradiction.

**a):** why in the sufficiency part, $X$ is **open** and he said an **open subspace** of a **sequential** spaces is **sequential**?

**b):** why in the last line of necessity part, we say that $C$ is **not compact**?
(c): In The  one point compatification, $‎\infty‎ \not\in X $ but in the proof said that "if  $‎\infty‎ \in C$? **Why?**

Answer (score 0):

You stated the theorem incorrectly. It should read:

> The one-point compactification of a countable $KC$ space $X$ is $KC$ if and only if $X$ is sequential.

1. Let $Y$ be the one-point compactification of $X$, and suppose that $Y$ is $KC$; then $Y$ is sequential by Corollary $3$ of the paper. $Y$ is $T_1$, so $X=Y\setminus\{\infty\}$ is open in $Y$ and is therefore sequential.
2. Let $A=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$. Without loss of generality the map $\omega\to A:n\mapsto x_n$ is injective, so for each $n\in\omega$ the set $S_n=\{p\}\cup\{x_k:k\ge n\}$ is compact and therefore closed in $X$. Let $n\in\omega$. $X$ is $T_1$, so $x_n$ has an open nbhd $U_n$ in $X$ such that $x_k\notin U_n$ if $k<n$. Let $V_n=U_n\setminus S_{n+1}$; then $V_n$ is an open nbhd of $x_n$, and $V_n\cap A=\{x_n\}$. Thus, $A$ is a discrete set in $X$, and since $\infty$ is not an accumulation point of $A$ in $Y$, $A$ is actually an infinite discrete set in $Y$. $A$ has no accumulation point in $C$, so $A$ is an infinite, closed, discrete subset of $C$, and hence $C$ cannot be compact.
3. $C$ is a subset of $Y$, not $X$, so it's entirely possible that $\infty\in C$.