# US not implies Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

On this page [US not implies Hausdorff](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/US_not_implies_Hausdorff) there is a supposed example, the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{N}$, of space that is a US-space but not $T_2$. But the sequence $x_k=k$ has infinite limits, in fact every natural number is a limit of such sequence. I agree on the other hand that the space is not Hausdorff.

> 1. is my observation on the example correct?
> 2. is there any easy example? other than [An anti-Hausdorff Fréchet-Urysohn US space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000161), [PDF](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864193901476) (honestly 12 pages for a simple counterexample is too much for me)?

Comment: You could use the weaker [example by Franklin and Rajagopalan](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-155-02/S0002-9947-1971-0283742-7/S0002-9947-1971-0283742-7.pdf). See Example 3.2 at the very end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the co-finite topology on an infinite set is *not* an example of a US-space which is not Hausdorff, for exactly the reason you mention.

There is a simple modification that makes it work, however. Instead of the co-finite topology on an infinite set, take the *co-countable* topology on an uncountable set. It is clearly not Hausdorff. For US-ness, note that the only convergent sequences are the eventually constant sequences, and their unique limit is the (eventually) constant value.

Answer (score 1):

Today the pi-Base has [six examples](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%2B%7E%24T_2%24).

- [Countable complement topology on the real numbers](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000017)
- [One Point Compactification of the Rationals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000029)
- [Square of One Point Compactification of the Rationals](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000031)
- [$\omega_1+1$ with endpoint doubled](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000037)
- [Maximal compact topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000097)
- [One-point compactification of the Arens-Fort space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165)

In general here's a trick. Take a [countable sequential Hausdorff space $X$ that's not weakly locally compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24T_2%24%2BCountable%2BSequential%2B%7EWeakly%20Locally%20Compact). Due to the lack of weak local compactness, its one-point compactification will no longer be Hausdorff. But the result will still have the "KC" property that [compacts are closed](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000100) via [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/465942/). Finally, [all KC spaces are US](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=KC%2B%7EUS).